# What is the best way to extract the OTP part of a string like below

Tags: java, selenium

Your One Time Password (OTP) for Member Portal login is 123456 and is valid for 15 minutes.

I just wants the OTP.

Also,

static String text="Your One Time Password (OTP) for Member Portal login is 968242 and is valid for 15 minutes.";

I want to update the above string to fetch the email with otp different each time. How should I update the text.

Below is the code I am using.

```
static String Subject="OTP for Member Portal login";

static String text="Your One Time Password (OTP) for Member Portal login is 968242 and is valid for 15 minutes.";

                static SendEmail obj=new SendEmail();

                public static void main(String[] args) {



                                try {

                                                obj.sendEmail(Subject,text);
                                                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]");
                                                String numberOnly = pattern.matcher(text).replaceAll("");
                                                System.out.println(numberOnly);
                                                System.out.println(numberOnly);
```

Comment: `[^0-9]` this should be `[^0-9]{6}`

Comment: @cruisepandey Hi.. This did not work. I got other characters as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am understanding right, you want to get the first number?

If text is always in the same format(as in:
"Your One Time Password (OTP) for Member Portal login is XXXXXX and is valid for 15 minutes."), something simple like should do the trick.

```
String[] arrayText = text.split(" ");
System.out.println(arrayText[10]);
```

This will print XXXXXX with the above text for example

---

Now if you wanted to change the number above with a new one, but keep the rest of the text, you can do this with a StringBuffer after changing arrayText[10] to the new number.

for example:

```
String text = "Your One Time Password (OTP) for Member Portal login is 968242 and is valid for 15 minutes.";
String[] arrayText = text.split(" ");
String newNumber = "123456";

StringBuffer newText = new StringBuffer();
for(i=0; i<arrayText.length; i++){
    newText.append(arrayText[i]);
    if(i != arrayText.length - 1) newText.append(" "); // Doing this to avoid extra space at the end
}


System.out.println(newText.toString());
```

---

I hope this solves your question - still a bit unsure on what exactly your meant.

Comment: Getting the OTP worked. But the second part is a little different.  What I am trying to do is connect to Outlook mail and read the mail with a particular subject and the text in which the OTP always changes. For Eg. <Your One Time Password (OTP) for Member Portal login is 968242 and is valid for 15 minutes."> In this text the OTP will change each time. I need to update the code in such a way that the mail is read each time and the OTP is fetched from mail.